# no NamespaceDetails for index error in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I get following issue with my mongodb:

> db.snmpsettings.find()

```
{
    "$err" : "no NamespaceDetails for index: { name: \"_id_\", ns: \"makalu.snmpsettings\", key: { _id: 1 }, v: 0 }",
    "code" : 17329
}
```

Because of following error I am unable to run my whole application. I can neither delete, remove or update the collection. Please help.
I am using mongodb version 2.6.10 in Ubuntu.

Comment: do you have too many collections in the same db? Looks like you need to repair your collection/db.

Comment: I tried repairing too but the repairing exists with exception in the same collection. :(